# TVML: adding new lines to a description text

Tags: apple-tv, tvml

Experimenting with Apple TV's TVML: I'm using a Product Template, and in the description field I'd like to add carriage returns, to make it look somewhat like a list.

Here is a simple example:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
        <productTemplate>
            <banner>
                <infoList>
                </infoList>
                <stack>
                    <title>Big Title</title>
                    <description>
                        Line one
                        Line two
                    </description>
                </stack>
            </banner>
        </productTemplate>
    </document>`
}
```

I've tried `\n`, `&#xD`, `&#xA` between the lines, and even something like this:

```
<![CDATA[
  Line 1 <br />
  Line 2 <br />
]]>
```

But none of these work. Is there a way to incorporate line breaks in TVML descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this code in a `template.xml.js` and loading it via the `Presenter.js` in the TVMLCatalog example from apple:

```
<stack>
    <description>Insert your \n username (tipically your ID)</description>
</stack>
```

It renders

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works. (Don't quite understand why it didn't work for me before - it was the first thing I tried - but it's working for me now)

Comment: It looks like "sometext\n moreText" or "some text \nmoretext" doesn't work. you need the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
var Template = function() {
  const description = `
    Line 1
    Line 2
  `.trim();

  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
      <productTemplate>
        <banner>
          <infoList>
          </infoList>
          <stack>
            <title>Big Title</title>
            <description>
              ${description}
            </description>
          </stack>
        </banner>
      </productTemplate>
    </document>`
}
```